# How Does Laravel Octane Handle In-Memory Data Persistence to Database?

Tags: php, laravel, swoole, octane

I have a question regarding data persistence in Laravel Octane. How long does it take for the in-memory data managed by Octane to be actually written to the database?

I've noticed that when I use the octane:reload command, some in-memory data seems to be lost. However, if I use octane:stop followed by octane:start, the in-memory data is not lost. This observation has led to a concern: if I don't stop Octane, how long will it take for these data to be written to the database? What is the underlying mechanism for this process?

Is there any specific documentation that explains how data persistence is handled in Laravel Octane?

Thank you for your assistance.